# Should I check whether there is a eth in contract

Tags: solidity

I cannot understand when the revert is running. I have this code:

```
function test() public payable returns(uint){
        require(getContractBalance() >= msg.value.add(msg.value).add(_foo), "Not enough eth in contract");
        _foo= _foo.add(msg.value.mul(5).div(1000));
        return _foo;
    }
```

In contract I have 2 ETH, and `_foo` var have 1e18 wei;

When I call the `test()` function and send 1 ETH, I don't have revert, and the function is run in the same way. But while 1ETH+1ETH+1ETH = 3ETH, in the contract I have only 2 ETH.

Why does revert not work? Is this because the `require()` is running after the changes in the contract? How can I do this: revert when the contract does not have enough eth!

Should I check whether there is a eth in the contract? If I call some function that sends ETH to an account, but I don't have eth in the contract I get revert? Should I check contract balance?

Should I set `require(addres(this).balance > 0)` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your require does not fail, because when you are starting with a contract with balance 2 ETH and you send 1 ETH along with the call of test, then the contract balance becomes 3 ETH and the condition for the require is satisfied.

So, you have to revisit your logic, e.g. by checking if `getContractBalance() - msg.value >= <desired-start-value-before-the-call>`